# Wordpress in subdirectory nginx 404 permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs, nginx

I am trying to add wordpress in subdirectory `/blog` with react application running in root. Wordpress have been installed successfully and working correctly with simple permalinks:

`https://foo.com/blog/?p=8
https://foo.com/blog/?page_id=8`

but returns 404 error when using pretty permalinks like:

`https://foo.com/blog/postname/`

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name foo.com;

    return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name foo.com;

    root /data/www/foo;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
    }


    location /learn {
            root /data/www/foo;
            index index.php index.html index.htm
            try_files $uri $uri/ /learn/index.php?$args;
    }


    location ~ /blog/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        root /data/www/foo;
    }


    location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks!
`

Comment: Your configuration is incomplete. It is difficult to see how you have partitioned PHP for `/learn` and `/blog`.

Comment: did you resolve this?